# Angular2. ng2-bootstrap in lazy loaded module needs app root module for some reason

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

RC6. Using modal component from ng2-bootstrap. Was working fine until I separated the application into modules. Now in lazy loaded module when I try to call `.show()` method of the modal component I'm getting an error: `No provider for AppComponent!`

As you may guessed the AppComponent is my main/default component in the app root module. How does this modal thing even know about AppComponent existence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because of this hack to get root app component:

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/components/utils/components-helper.service.ts#L41-L49

Comment: Thanks, Do you know if there's an ETA on fixing this?

Comment: Reason found, working on solution (have couple of ideas), need to test them on failing sample

Comment: My project is quite large and complicated to publish on plunker I can try if you give me your changes.